# wxPython: Making a scrollable DC

Tags: python, wxpython, scroll, scrollbar

I am drawing inside a wx.Window using a PaintDC. I am drawing circles and stuff like that into that window. Problem is, sometimes the circles go outside the scope of the window. I want a scrollbar to automatically appear whenever the drawing gets too big. What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `wx.ScrolledWindow` and set the size of the window as soon as your 'drawing go outside' the window with

```
SetVirtualSize(width,height)
```

If this size is bigger than the client size, then wx will show scrollbars. When drawing in the window make sure to use `CalcUnscrolledPosition` and `CalcScrolledPosition`

[Here](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxscrolledwindow.html) you can find some more information.

Comment: I didn't fully understand. Do I need to calculate on my own how much width and height the drawings take? Because I don't understand how to get the "width" and "height" inputs for SetVirtualSize.

Comment: If your circle is 10 pixel wider than your screen, then add 10 to the current client size and you have the new width.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand yet. Assume I draw all kinds of different things into that DC. Is it my responsibility to keep track of how much space my drawing takes?